# Parse Array [ How to prevent user from voting multiple times]

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I have an app in which you can upvote things, similar to Facebook likes or Reddit upvotes. You get the picture.

Well, I figured it would just be simple. I have an array column in Parse. For every message that gets an upvote, the user's name gets added to the array in that specific post's row. Except I need to prevent the user from voting an infinite amount of times. Here is what I tried after reading

```
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query3 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");
            query3.whereContains("objectId", objectId);
            query3.whereContains("PostVoteUsers", mCurrentUser.getUsername());
            query3.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                List<String> list11 =  new ArrayList<String>();

                public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                  ParseObject p = messages.get(0);
                  if(p.getList("PostVoteUsers").contains(mCurrentUser.getUsername())==false)
                    list11 = p.getList("ParseVoteUsers");

                    if(list11.contains(mCurrentUser.getUsername()))
                uparrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");
                query2.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                  public void done(ParseObject messages, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        int votes = messages.getInt("PostVotes") + 1;

                        messages.add("PostVoteUsers", mCurrentUser.getUsername());
                        messages.put("PostVotes", votes);

                        postvote.setText("" + votes);

                        messages.saveInBackground();

                    }
                   }
                  });


                }
            });
                }}});
```

It doesn't work. Everything I try gets me with a nullpointer exception. I've tried a few other things too, but I figured I may be looking at the wrong questions.

In the class "Messages," I have an array column called "PostVoteUsers."

Once and for all, how can I find out if the user is in a specific row's array?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2AEq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that determines whether the user is in your object's array similar to this:

```
public boolean canBeLiked() {
    String ids = getJSONArray("likedBy").toString();
    if (ids.contains(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But change that to work for you. It works for me. Get the JSONArray of your ParseObject, make it a string, and then call contains(ParseUser.getCurrent().getObjectId()) on that string.